# Вывод значений из MySQL в таблицу с помощью PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Помогите пожалуйста. У меня есть таблица с результатами тестов, пройденных пользователями.
ID Пользователя, Дата теста, Баллы.

Мне нужно вывести в таблицу  результаты для каждого пользователя. Но чтобы другие результаты видны не были.

На данный момент такой вот код

```
<tr style="font-weight: 700;">
<td>Дата прохождения</td>
<td>Результат</td>
</tr>
<!-- Присваиваем переменной moyaidi - значение ID авторизованного пользоваетля -->   
<?php 
$moyaidi = $_SESSION['user']['id'];
?>
<!-- Проходимся циклом по данным из базы mysql -->     
<?php for ($i=0;$i<count($resss);$i++) {?>
<tr>
<!-- Вытаскиваем все имена --> 
<td><?php 
<!-- Проверяем, чтобы ID авторизованного пользователя совпадал с ID в таблице БД результатов теста -->  
if ($moyaidi == $resss[$i]['myid'])
echo $resss[$i]['data'];?></td>
<!-- Вытаскиваем все результаты --> 
<td><?php 
<!-- Проверяем, чтобы ID авторизованного пользователя совпадал с ID в таблице БД результатов теста -->  
if ($moyaidi == $resss[$i]['myid'])
echo $resss[$i]['result']
?></td>
<?php }?>
</tr>
```

Условия в ячейки добавил я.
P.S. Код писал разработчик, у которого была задача выводить вообще все результаты для всех.

Работает, но криво. Теперь если я захожу под собой - я вижу свои результаты, всё ок. Но мне еще выводит пустые строки с результатами других (которые не видны).Но сами строчки есть.

Помогите пожалуйста, полагаю проблема в написании цикла.

Comment: Покажите SQL запрос

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Если надо решить сугубо эту проблему то можно обернуть весь `<tr></tr>` в условие. А так лучше смотреть на ответ Егора Банина ниже https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1256409/241547 все правильно сказал :)

```
<tr style="font-weight: 700;">
    <td>Дата прохождения</td>
    <td>Результат</td>
</tr>
<!-- Присваиваем переменной moyaidi - значение ID авторизованного пользователя -->
<?php
$moyaidi = $_SESSION['user']['id'];
?>
<!-- Проходимся циклом по данным из базы mysql -->
<?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($resss); $i++) { ?>
    <?php if ($moyaidi == $resss[$i]['myid']) { ?>
        <tr>
            <!-- Вытаскиваем все имена -->
            <td>
                <?php echo $resss[$i]['data']; ?>
            </td>
            <!-- Вытаскиваем все результаты -->
            <td>
                <?php echo $resss[$i]['result']; ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы решили проблему, отфильтровав из всех значений только те, которые связанны с вашим id. Это работает, но это некрасиво и неэффективно. Вы получаете, а затем обходите в цикле все записи, хотя вам нужны только некоторые из них. Если пользователей будет много, это станет проблемой. Правильнее было бы выбрать только нужные вам записи. MySQL позволяет это сделать. Надо только добавить соответствующее условие WHERE. Если вы ещё не знакомы с возможностями и синтаксисом SQL, то обязательно найдите время чтобы познакомиться.

Предположим, что пока вариант с фильтрацией вас устраивает. Как понять что не так с кодом, генерирующим HTML таблицы? Надо посмотреть на этот HTML. В браузере вы видите то, как сгенерированный HTML был интерпретирован и отображён браузером. Это может сбивать с толку. Смотрите HTML (ctrl+u). Вы увидите что-то вроде:

```
<tr></tr>
<tr>
    <td>Данные пользователя</td>
    <td>Результаты пользователя</td>
</tr>
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr>
```

Вас должны насторожить пустые строки (tr -- table row -- строка таблицы) `<tr></tr>`. Откуда они взялись? Их легко найти в коде, где они выводятся на каждой итерации в цикле, так как не помещены в условие.

Отчасти ваше затруднение при попытке решить проблему связано с тем, что код не структурирован и его сложно воспринимать. Вы можете помочь себе и другим программистам, которые когда-нибудь как и вы столкнуться с этим кодом, если сделаете код более читаемым.

1. Сначала подготовьте данные

Всё что вы хотите сделать с данными, лучше сделать до того, как вы начнёте формировать HTML. Переместите всё, что не относится к выводу HTML наверх, в отдельный блок `<?php ... ?>`.

2. Используйте [альтернативный синтаксис](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) для циклов и условий

Проблема классического синтаксиса в том, что он использует фигурные скобки и для циклов и для условий. Разбираться чья это фигурная скобка сложно. Используйте альтернативный синтаксис.

3. Разделите циклы и условия и вывод значений, используйте отступы

Если выполнить пункты 1 и 2, то PHP-код в HTML можно встраивать однострочными кусочками схожими с тегами. Такой код легко выровнять отступами, обозначая вложенность.

```
<?php

$userId = $_SESSION['user']['id']?? null;
$tests = array_filter($resss, function($row) use($userId) {
    return $row['myid'] == $userId;
});

?>
...

<?php foreach($tests as $test): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?= htmlspecialchars($test['data']) ?></td>
        <td><?= htmlspecialchars($test['result']) ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach ?>

...
```

Вам не обязательно делать фильтрацию через [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-filter.php), можно использовать и if. Но обязательно обратите внимание на использование [htmlspecialchars](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.htmlspecialchars). Данные пользователя и результаты могут содержать символы имеющие специальное значение в HTML (например, что если пользователя зовут `<script>alert(document.cookie);</script>`?). Чтобы не допустить ошибок и [XSS-уязвимостей](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B6%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3) всегда используйте htmlspecialchars, если выводите текст в HTML.

Кроме всего прочего, постарайтесь давать переменным подходящие названия. Если вы не сильны в английском, то используйте онлайн-переводчик. Не пишите очевидных комментариев, пишите только те, которые могут быть полезны другим программистам (например можно написать: `// пока не разобрался как выбрать данные только одного пользователя из базы данных, фильтрую тут`). Пишите комментарии в соответстувющем контексте (в примере кода вы комментируете в HTML то, что пишите в PHP). Про названия переменных и правильные комментарии (и другие важные для программиста вещи) есть целая книга [Совершенный код (Стив Макконнелл)](https://g.co/kgs/o6RjcP), когда-нибудь прочитайте её.

Будьте внимательны к коду и сохраняйте любознательность, и тогда очень скоро вы станете крутым программистом :-)

Answer (score -1):

Друзья, всем спасибо за помощь! Решил проблему следующим образом

```
<?php for ($i=0;$i<count($resss);$i++) {?>
<tr>
<!-- Вытаскиваем все имена -->                
<?php 
if ($moyaidi == $resss[$i]['myid'])
echo "<td>".$resss[$i]['data']."</td>";                   
?>
<!-- Вытаскиваем все результаты --> 
<?php             
if ($moyaidi == $resss[$i]['myid'])
echo "<td>".$resss[$i]['result']."</td>";
?>                            
<?php }?>
</tr>               
</table>
```

Закинул td в эхо)
К сожалению, увидел ваши ответы только сегодня, в любом случае, спасибо огромное!

Comment: Надо принять ответ Егора Банина. Даже если ты из него ничего не понял, все равно надо принять именно его. И возвращаться к нему каждый день, пока не поймешь и не реализуешь все что там написано.